# how can i run an sql file with multipile create commands using php without manually parsing the sql file?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm building a web application using PHP5.3 and Zend Framework 1.9.4.
i have an sql file that creates and populates the relevant tables.

is there a way to install this sql file using PHP or even some component of Zend Framework ?
for now i just search for the mysql client binary and install using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you explain why parsing is not wanted? If your data is such that " `) ; \n`" or maybe just "`) ;`" can be used as a delimiter string then you can read the entire file into a string ( [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) ) and break into parts ( strtok ) in totally 3-4 lines.

( Or you could look at phpmyadmin source code if that is available to you, but that's very unwise to use like that )

Comment: actually it seems that you are correct, i can divide the sql file by the delimiter ; and run each command individually. the problem is that sometimes ';' can show up in comments or in texts in some tables. how can i do a proper parsing ?

Comment: For strtok() a delmiter need not be a single character, but can be a string.  Hence ");\n" will separate at only those places where a line separates 2 queries ending with a semi-colon.

Try some small sample before running the full file. It is worth learning by trial-and-error because it is totally 3-4 lines and you will learn something about parsing general text which is a useful skill to have.

Try it out, it will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For my Zend Framework projects, I do this using Ant's SQL task, so when I deploy the application using Ant, it runs the sql script to create the tables (if they don't exist). I think you could also do the same thing with phing, if you are familiar with that.

Sorry, that's not really a direct answer to your question, but if you use something like Ant it can get the job done for you.

Comment: thanks i'll take a look and see if these components will implement nice with my application.

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked with explode(';',$string) then loop through resulted parts and after checking if trimmed version of the current part is not blank simply ran mysql_query() in a error catching construction (so i don't get that 'blank execution' error)